# How to push changes from Git repository to Subversion

Tags: git, git-svn

I am trying to learn how to use GIT with SVN repository (I know SVN, but total newbie in GIT).

I have fetched the SVN repository, but I don't understand how to push back to the SVN. The command "git svn dcommit" commit all the changes done on the GIT branch, but how can I choose which files to push (stage files for SVN commit)?

I might be really missing something out because this whole concept is a bit new to me, so any explaination would be really appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation? http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn - it says everything you need to know, plus it has some examples (search for 'basic examples' in that page)

Comment: @Augusto - yes, but I did not see any reference to staging files, or dcommiting some of the files. I saw that I can dcommit interactively which means that for every patch I will be asked if I agree or not, but that is not what I am looking for....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do `git svn dcommit` when your local git history on top of svn remote is what you'd like to see in svn. Normally you do more frequent local commits when working with git. You have your working directory clean before dcommitting. See basic git manuals, especially `add` `commit` `rebase` and `stash`. Please be aware that working with git-svn might require stronger git skills than with normal git remote in many but the simplest workflows.

Comment: But how do I dcommit only some of my git commits?

Comment: That's where it gets bit cumbersome. You will need to rearrange your commits with git rebase interactive so that pushed to svn are all before the remaining, then checkout the last of those to be pushed and say `git svn dcommit`. Dcommit will rebase the pushed commits so you will need to rebase remained commits on top of just pushed.

Answer (score 0):

In case I want to dcommit only **some** of the GIT commits to the SVN, you can make a temp branch and cherry-pick commits to dcommit into this temp branch. Now when the temp branch is with the commits you want, you dcommit it.